# Check click when not button is clicked in a container

Tags: jquery

I have a container, in that container i have a button.

If i click the container i want to have some panel slideDown (works already)
but when i click the button i dont want the panel to slide down.

this is the code i am using

```
$(function(){
    //.sonata-purchases-container > .list-group-item
    $('.sonata-purchases-container > .list-group > .list-group-item:not(.admin-shop-resend)').click(function(event){

        var infoContainer = $(this).find('.purchases-info');
        infoContainer.slideToggle();

    });
})
```

However even when i state the not selector, the panel always drops down when i click the button.

I tried using the target attribute on the click event but on the button it can be that you click the button itsself or the button its span text

button code:

```
<button class="pull-right btn btn-default admin-shop-resend" value="somevalue">
    <span class="text">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh text-success"></i>
        Resend
    </span>
</button>
```

.purchases-info is the panel that slides down

Comment: Please share fiddle..

Comment: my bad, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/3EWJj/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/3EWJj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `event.stopPropagation()` , it is used to stop event bubbling in DOM .

```
$(function(){
    //.sonata-purchases-container > .list-group-item
    $('.sonata-purchases-container').click(function(event){
        var infoContainer = $(this).find('.purchases-info');
        infoContainer.slideToggle();

    });
})
$(document).on('click','#pullbutton',function(event)
               {
                     event.stopPropagation();
               });
```